# Beginner (Python 3.6.1): Why isn't this script working?

Tags: algorithm, python-3.x

Keep in mind I've only started learning Python (first language) a few days back.

I'm trying to find the greatest prime factor of a given (and potentially big) integer 'a'. I start by defining a function prime(n) that checks whether an integer 'n' is prime or not. I then find factors 'n' of 'a' from biggest to smallest and check each with prime(n). If a prime n is found, it is printed out and I use break to end the process. If n=1 is the only prime factor found, then 'a' is prime, and so its greatest prime factor is itself.

This script fails completely. The variable n_prime goes back to whatever value I first give it even after prime(n) should change it to either True or False. If I start with it being None, after prime(n), it always remain None.

I hope it isn't too messy, and that there aren't too many issues with my code.

```
def prime(n): 
if n == 1:
    n_prime = False

if n == 2:
    n_prime = True

if n == 3:
    n_prime = True

if n % 2 == 0 and n_prime != True:
    n_prime = False

else:
    for i in range(3, n, 2):
        if i != n:
            if n % i == 0:
                n_prime = False
                break
        else:
            n_prime = True



n_prime = None
a = int(input())

for n in range (a-1, 1, -1):

     if a % n == 0:
          prime(n)
          if n_prime==True:
               if n != 1:
                   print(n, ' is the greatest prime factor of ', a)
                   break
               else:
                   print(a, 'is the greatest prime factor of ', a)
                   break
```

Comment: I don't know if this was a typo in your copy to the post, but the entire block of code following `def prime(n):` needs to be indented.

Comment: Your indents look off.

Comment: In my code, it's fine. It's a copy paste issue.

Comment: You should use `return` instead of a global variable to get the result of `prime`.

Comment: Since indentation is significant in Python, you should really fix that copy and paste issue (otherwise it is hard to tell when the function ends and other code begins).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code doesn't work because your `prime` function doesn't modify the global variable `n_prime` the way it looks like you're expecting it to. You *could* make it work by adding a `global` statement at the top of the function: `global n_prime`. But that's not the best approach. Modifying global variables from within a function loses much of the benefits a function gives.

A better way is to `return` the value you want to use in the calling code:

```
def prime(n): 
    if n == 2 or n == 3: # We can reorder and combine some of the conditions up here
        return True # return instead of trying to assign to the global variable!

    if n == 1 or n % 2 == 0:
        return False

    for i in range(3, n, 2): # The end value of a range is not used in the iteration.
        if n % i == 0:       # So the logic that was checking `i != n` is unnecessary.
            return False

    return True  # if the loop finished without returning, we know our value is prime
```

Here's how I'd use that function in the greatest prime factor algorithm you showed:

```
a = int(input())

for n in range (a-1, 1, -1): # This loop stops at 2. It doesn't ever reach 1, but that's OK!
    if a % n == 0 and prime(n): # Test the return value from the function here!
        print(n, ' is the greatest prime factor of ', a)
        break
else: # This else block is attached to the loop. It runs only if the loop didn't `break`.
    print(a, 'is the greatest prime factor of ', a)
```

Note that it's not necessary to compare a boolean value to another one (with e.g. `n_prime == True`. Just use the boolean value directly in an `if` (or with a boolean operator like `and` or `or`).

I'd also note that you could get rid of the special case at the end (for when `a` is prime), and simply change the loop to start with `a` instead of `a-1`. Since you check if `n` is prime after seeing that it's a divisor, this will only print out the message if the `prime` function confirms that `a` has no factors (other than itself and one).